# How is the GSM Call Flow implemented and when is the microphone opened?

Tags: networking, mobile-network, gsm, telephony

Is it possible to know how is the GSM call flow implemented on Android? I will like to know concretely when its the microphone opened.

Comment: You can always check the source and find out yourself. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Right now it's difficult for us to know what kind of answer will help you.

Comment: @DanHulme What I want to know concretely is if when making a call, during the ringing, is the microphone already opened  ? As far as I know the GSM flow requires CC_CONNECT_ACKNOWLEDGE before entering the speech phase. I've read this weird behaviour in forums i.e https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/511235-s4-without-answering-call-caller-can-hear-my-conversation-how-even-possible.html

thanks for your interest.